# OkHttpClient broken after updated Retrofit to Retrofit 2

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

I got this error after updated from retrofit to retrofit2.

> FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
>                                                                                Process: nz.co.datacom.mars.junction, PID: 21616
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method
>   log(Ljava/lang/String;)V in class Lokhttp3/internal/Platform; or its
>   super classes (declaration of 'okhttp3.internal.Platform' appears in
>   /data/app/nz.co.datacom.mars.junction-1/base.apk)
>   at
>   okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor$Logger$1.log(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:109)
>   at
>   okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:157)
>   at
>   okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:190)
>   at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:163)
>   at okhttp3.RealCall.access$100(RealCall.java:30)
>   at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:127)
>   at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

The libs version I used in the app are:

```
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.7'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.2.0'
```

Not really sure if it is because of the okhttp version or not, but I tried few different version between 2.3.0 and 3.4.0 and none of them work.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 20):

Had the same problem as you.

First of all, throw out:

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
```

Retrofit has `okhttp3` as it's dependency so it is not needed. Moreover, when you check [here](http://www.methodscount.com/?lib=com.squareup.retrofit2%3Aretrofit%3A2.1.0) `Retrofit 2.1.0` depends on `okhttp 3.3.0`, so there might be a conflict. Remember, that the final dependency version is the one you write in `gradle` file. If you don't write it, then `Gradle` automatically resolves it and fetches the right version.

There is also a newer version of Logging Interceptor and urlconnection:

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.4.1'
```

Hope that solves the problem.

Answer (score 3):

In addition, the most important thing to understand the fix is to ensure that okhttp3 dependencies have all the same version number as stated [here](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2839#issuecomment-264004963) by collaborators